# UIButton - text truncated

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've created a wide UIButton with Interface Builder (Xcode 4), added in a dummy 5 character title (e.g. Click) and then changed the title text programmatically later.

Odd thing is the width of the title text seems to remain the same so, if I use a longer piece of text (e.g. "Now click here"), it appears like this: "N...e"

Any idea what's going on?

UPDATE:
If I use a long line of text in IB it's centred. However, once I've programmatically-changed this text it appears left-aligned!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to use the `UIButton` method `setTitle:forState:`

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Correct New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

as this will correctly update the size and position of the buttons label. Where as just setting the title with `self.myButton.titleLabel.text = @"Wrong New Title";` will not.

Comment: I agree. The currently selected answer works but isn't idiomatic.