# Button title text not showing fully

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am using Xcode 4.2 iOS 5.0 and also using storyboard. I have simple button and I connected that button with outlet.Now I am changing the button text from code.Problem is that if my string of button title is that "hey how are you?" then it is showing in button title "hey....u?" .Can anyone suggest me where I am doing wrong or missing something else?

![enter image description here][1]
This is IB Settings.
I just wrote btw.textLabel.text=textstr; and frame is (0,0,290,42) and text str is time as for e.g [NSDate date]

Comment: I don't know why it is?Can u suggest me how shall I increase it?

Comment: @ARC But it seems you accepted answers which weren't really answers, so that isnt' much help either.

Comment: I removed my acceptance did u observed that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIButton - text truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538196/uibutton-text-truncated)

Answer (score 6):

Your button width is smaller than the title string's length.that's why
it truncates the middle part of the string. You can set the content
mode to characterWrap in IB to make the title in two lines or  you can
change the font size to a smaller one to fit in your button width or 
you can change the button width to occupy the whole string. Prefer
what is fine for you.

Comment: Your Line break is still in the Truncate Middle option(in IB).Change it to characterWrap.

Comment: Actually I did not know that time how it is accepted in stack overflow At that time I did it for testing it:)

Comment: @Sree after changing it is not displaying anything

Comment: @ARC:Please provide the bottom section of your IB settings

Answer (score 2):

Try [myButton sizeToFit]; //I need to type 9 more characters to answer this question due to 30 char minimum.

Comment: Not working in my case.Thanks for suggestion.Do u have any other solutions??

Comment: Not working means what? The button doesn't resize at all, not enough?

Comment: Title goes to top left side of button and previously it was in middle of button and "......" is still there

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this already worked in XCode 4.2, but now it does ;)

You need to use the `UIButton` method `setTitle:forState:`

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"Correct New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

as this will correctly update the size and position of the buttons label. Where as just setting the title with `self.myButton.titleLabel.text = @"Wrong New Title";` will not.

Credits to James Beith (see his Answer in [UIButton - text truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538196/uibutton-text-truncated))

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.textLabel.text = @"some very long title";
[myButton.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOR SWIFT 4,5**

You need to use "setTitle" instead of "textLabel.text"

```
Button.setTitle("this is maximium line text come", for: .normal)
```